# MySQL duplicate entry error #1062

Tags: mysql

I'm running a trim query to remove any rows with a trailing "-" in the slug column.

I have rows with duplicates but that is required right now.

How can I fix the error so that it runs the trim query?

```
UPDATE terms
SET slug = TRIM(TRAILING '-' FROM slug);
```

The error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'system' for key 'slug'`

Comment: What's the error ? Can you show it please ...

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry 'system' for key 'slug'

Comment: You have 2 rows where slug column contains system and system- e.g. one with "system" and another with "system-"

Comment: Yup, that's correct. But because they both reference 2 different things (set by their ID's), i must keep both. Maybe taking off the unique on slud will have to be the answer..

Comment: Then remove from slug and set another column to UNIQUE key or add a new column to define UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint set on the `slug` column, you must remove that:

```
ALTER TABLE terms DROP INDEX my_unique_constraint
```

Please note that the above will work only for MySQL - the statement varies as per the database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like column slug is defined as UNIQUE or Primary KEY. If you want to keep the duplicate records, you may need to remove UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY from this column or/and introduce different PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE column.

Comment: How could a duplicate be existing in that slug column if it was declared to have pirmary/unique keys? :$

Comment: @bonCodigo: there are no duplicates *now*, but the error implies that after executing the `TRIM` , there will be.

Comment: @DCoder is right, before TRIM there is no duplicate rows. e.g. one row contains "a" and 2nd contains "a-". But after TRIM, both will have a which is not allowed as the column is defined as UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Thanks guys. Any idea what I should do then?

Comment: If you want to keep both the rows containing system in slug column then you should remove UNIQUE constraint from slug and define another column as PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE. Or don't define UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY at all after removing the existing KEY. It all depends how you want to solve this conflict.

Comment: @mwasif that makes more sense then ;) +1